# A noun to refer to a "dispersal of a rally"

Tags: word-choice

What's the usual noun in English to describe an act by the police to disperse an illegal rally?

I want to come up with a title for a video clip. A noun would fit there better - especially if the title goes like

> "A violent (*noun*) by the police in (*the name of town*)"

Could I say "**dispersal** of a rally"? Or would that sound weird?

EDIT:

I just want to come up with a title for a video clip. A noun would fit there better - especially if the title goes like "A violent (noun) by the police in (the name of town)"

Comment: ***Usually***, I doubt many native Anglophones would even ***try*** to talk about the situation using a ***noun*** to reference "the act of the splitting up a group of people, causing them to leave in different directions", so it doesn't really matter whether "dispersal" might be the best choice or not. We'd just say *The police dispersed the crowd* and move on. Things like ***The police's dispersal of the crowd was excessively violent*** just sound "affected" to me.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I suggest, "A violent disruption of a rally"

Comment: Please [edit] to include an explanation of *why* this is correct; answers without explanation do not teach the patterns of the language well. See the [Submitting Answers that merely answer the question](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1117) discussion on meta.